# How to find N values of 3D matrix that satisfy condition

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D array that is denoted by `features`. Each element of `feature` is a number `x`. Now I will get that number and calculate `g(x)` and `f(x)` of the number (`g` and `f` are functions of x).  My problem is how to get `N` maximization of absolute value between `g(x)` and `f(x)`. The function will return an array with `N` elements `x`. But I don't know how to get them. Could you help me?

This is my code:

```
%features is 3D array
%N is elements that we need
%Fs,sigmas,thetas are size of the array
% return N elements of features that maximization abs(f_s-g_s)
function features_filter=gabor_sort(features,N,Fs,sigmas,thetas)

for k = 1:numel(sigmas)
    for j = 1:numel(Fs)
        for i = 1:numel(thetas)
            x= features(:,:,k,j,i);
            f_x=x.^2;
            g_x=x.^3+1;
            s1=abs(f_x-g_x);
            %%Do something in here to get maximization of s1        
         end
    end
end

end
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want.  Do you want to return the `N` maximum values of `abs(f_x-g_x)` over **all** of the values in features, or do you want to return the features that correspond to the `N` maximum values of `abs(f_x-g_x)`?  Your problem description is unclear.

Comment: I want to find N values of features that satisfy abs(f_x-g_x) is maximization

Comment: So you want to find `N` features that maximize `abs(f_x-g_x)`?

Comment: `abs(f_x-g_x)` is a 2D matrix judging from your syntax.  What is your criteria in showing that a matrix from this computation is maximized in distance?  Do you sum up all of the values in the matrix?

Comment: Only 1D. Let think x is a value, f_x and g_x are also value. In my full code I use f_x=mean(x(:))...But for simple, I only assume x is value

Comment: Aha, ok then.  Let me write something up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem.  Create two matrices that will store the features we get for each combination of `sigma, Fs` and `theta`, as well as place your absolute values for each feature in this matrix, and when you're done, sort these distances in **descending** order.  We can then use the second parameter of [`sort`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) to give us the location of the features that maximize this distance.  In other words, do this:

```
%features is 3D array
%N is elements that we need
%Fs,sigmas,thetas are size of the array
% return N elements of features that maximization abs(f_x-g_x)
function features_filter=gabor_sort(features,N,Fs,sigmas,thetas)

s1 = []; % s1 array to store our distances
xFeatures = []; %// Features to return

for k = 1:numel(sigmas)
    for j = 1:numel(Fs)
        for i = 1:numel(thetas)
            x = features(:,:,k,j,i);
            xFeatures = cat(3,xFeatures,x); %// Stack features in a 3D matrix
            x = x(:); %// Convert to 1D as per your comments
            f_x=mean(x.^2); %// Per your comment
            g_x=mean(x.^3+1); %// Per your comment
            s1 = [s1 abs(f_x-g_x)]; %// Add to s1 array
        end
    end
end

[~,sortInd] = sort(s1, 'descend');

%// Return a 3D matrix where each slice is a feature matrix
%// The first slice is the one that maximized abs(f_x - g_x) the most
%// The second slice is the one that maximized abs(f_x - g_x) the second most, etc.
features_filter = xFeatures(:,:,sortInd(1:N));
```

---

Minor note: This code is untested.  I don't have access to your data, so I can't really reproduce.  Hope this works!

Comment: Thank you rayryeng. Your code return 3D matrix, right? How about if I only return 1D matrix that only store x value. Example features_filter=[x_1 x_2...x_N]. It will easy to access

Comment: If I want return 1D matrix I will do features_filter = features(:,:,sortInd(1:N));, Right?

Comment: @user3051460 - In that case, you would change `xFeatures = cat(3,xFeatures,x);` to `xFeatures = [xFeatures x];`.  After this, you would then do `features_filter = xFeatures(sortInd(1:N));`